# Unit Testing Umbraco 8 Composers

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, umbraco, umbraco8

I'm fairly new to unit testing so go easy on me! I'm attempting to use a fairly simple Umbraco 8 project as a bit of a test bed. I'm currently stuck on trying to test a composer which registers a dependency and having a tough time figuring out how to test it.

The code will probably speak volumes so without further ado, here's the composer I'd like to test. As you can see, it simply registers a service coded against an interface:

```
using Papermoon.Umbraco.Utils.Services;
using Papermoon.Umbraco.Utils.Services.Interfaces;
using Umbraco.Core;
using Umbraco.Core.Composing;

namespace Papermoon.Umbraco.Aldus.Core.Composers
{
    [RuntimeLevel(MinLevel = RuntimeLevel.Run)]
    public class ServicesComposer : IUserComposer
    {
        public void Compose(Composition composition)
        {
            composition.Register<IPapermoonContentTypeContainerService, PapermoonContentTypeContainerService>();
        }
    }
}
```

After a lot of playing around, I found some code in the Umbraco source which means I can get a test passing based on the idea of registering a type. However, that is in no way in context of the `ServicesComposer` class. Hence, that wouldn't count against my code coverage and actually testing the class, rather than the ability to register something. Here's the code anyway:

```
using System;
using Moq;
using NUnit.Framework;
using Papermoon.Umbraco.Aldus.Core.Composers;
using Papermoon.Umbraco.Utils.Services;
using Papermoon.Umbraco.Utils.Services.Interfaces;
using Umbraco.Core;
using Umbraco.Core.Cache;
using Umbraco.Core.Composing;
using Umbraco.Core.Composing.CompositionExtensions;
using Umbraco.Core.Logging;

namespace Papermoon.Umbraco.Aldus.Core.Tests.Composers
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class ServicesComposerTests
    {
        private ServicesComposer _servicesComposer;

        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            _servicesComposer = new ServicesComposer();
        }

        [Test]
        public void Compose_WhenCalled_RegistersContentTypeContainerService()
        {
            Func<IFactory, IFactory> factoryFactory = null;

            var mockedRegister = Mock.Of<IRegister>();
            var mockedFactory = Mock.Of<IFactory>();

            // the mocked register creates the mocked factory
            Mock.Get(mockedRegister)
                .Setup(x => x.CreateFactory())
                .Returns(mockedFactory);

            // the mocked register can register a factory factory
            Mock.Get(mockedRegister)
                .Setup(x => x.Register(It.IsAny<Func<IFactory, IFactory>>(), Lifetime.Singleton))
                .Callback<Func<IFactory, IFactory>, Lifetime>((ff, lt) => factoryFactory = ff);

            // the mocked factory can invoke the factory factory
            Mock.Get(mockedFactory)
                .Setup(x => x.GetInstance(typeof(IPapermoonContentTypeContainerService)))
                .Returns(() => new Mock<IPapermoonContentTypeContainerService>().Object);

            var logger = new ProfilingLogger(Mock.Of<ILogger>(), Mock.Of<IProfiler>());
            var typeLoader = new TypeLoader(Mock.Of<IAppPolicyCache>(), "", logger);
            var composition = new Composition(mockedRegister, typeLoader, logger, Mock.Of<IRuntimeState>());

            var factory = composition.CreateFactory();

            var resolved = factory.GetInstance<IPapermoonContentTypeContainerService>();

            Assert.IsNotNull(resolved);
        }
    }
}
```

And the below code shows where I am at the moment, and is probably close to what the test should look like (if a little messy currently). I'm potentially way off the mark here so any help would go down a storm!

```
using System;
using Moq;
using NUnit.Framework;
using Papermoon.Umbraco.Aldus.Core.Composers;
using Papermoon.Umbraco.Utils.Services;
using Papermoon.Umbraco.Utils.Services.Interfaces;
using Umbraco.Core;
using Umbraco.Core.Cache;
using Umbraco.Core.Composing;
using Umbraco.Core.Composing.CompositionExtensions;
using Umbraco.Core.Logging;

namespace Papermoon.Umbraco.Aldus.Core.Tests.Composers
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class ServicesComposerTests
    {
        private ServicesComposer _servicesComposer;

        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            _servicesComposer = new ServicesComposer();

            Current.Factory = new Mock<IFactory>().Object;
        }

        [Test]
        public void Compose_WhenCalled_RegistersContentTypeContainerService()
        {

            var mockedRegister = Mock.Of<IRegister>();

            var logger = new ProfilingLogger(Mock.Of<ILogger>(), Mock.Of<IProfiler>());
            var typeLoader = new TypeLoader(Mock.Of<IAppPolicyCache>(), "", logger);
            var composition = new Composition(mockedRegister, typeLoader, logger, Mock.Of<IRuntimeState>());

            _servicesComposer.Compose(composition);

            var resolved = Current.Factory.GetInstance<IPapermoonContentTypeContainerService>();

            Assert.IsNotNull(resolved);
        }
    }
}
```

I've also tried mocking up Composition to see if I could verify that the `Register` method has run but as this is a static method I get the following error:

```
Extension methods (here: RegisterExtensions.Register) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.
```

Here's the code that gets me to that error:

```
[Test]
public void Compose_WhenCalled_RegistersContentTypeContainerService()
{
    Func<IFactory, IFactory> factoryFactory = null;

    var mockedRegister = Mock.Of<IRegister>();
    var mockedFactory = Mock.Of<IFactory>();

    // the mocked register creates the mocked factory
    Mock.Get(mockedRegister)
        .Setup(x => x.CreateFactory())
        .Returns(mockedFactory);

    Mock.Get(mockedRegister)
        .Setup(x => x.Register(It.IsAny<Func<IFactory, IFactory>>(), Lifetime.Singleton))
        .Callback<Func<IFactory, IFactory>, Lifetime>((ff, lt) => factoryFactory = ff);

    // the mocked factory can invoke the factory factory
    Mock.Get(mockedFactory)
        .Setup(x => x.GetInstance(typeof(IFactory)))
        .Returns(() => factoryFactory?.Invoke(mockedFactory));

    var logger = new ProfilingLogger(Mock.Of<ILogger>(), Mock.Of<IProfiler>());
    var typeLoader = new TypeLoader(Mock.Of<IAppPolicyCache>(), "", logger);
    var composition = new Mock<Composition>(mockedRegister, typeLoader, logger, new Mock<IRuntimeState>().Object);

    composition.Verify(c => c.Register<IPapermoonContentTypeContainerService, PapermoonContentTypeContainerService>(It.IsAny<Lifetime>()));
}
```

Ultimately, I'm failing hard (and might have set my sights too high!), I'm not 100% sure on *what* to test here. My idea is that I want to test that the `IPapermoonContentTypeContainerService` is resolvable after `_serviceComposer.Compose` runs  i.e. it's not null which ensures that it's been registered to the container. Potentially this isn't possible at which point, I wondered if testing that `composition.Register<IPapermoonContentTypeContainerService, PapermoonContentTypeContainerService>();` was called was enough (as the actual registration part is third-party and therefore not to be tested). Or, am I barking up the wrong tree and this shouldn't actually be tested at all?

Thanks!

Ben

Comment: imo the umbraco team should change [the contract for IComposer](https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/853087a75044b814df458457dc9a1f778cc89749/src/Umbraco.Core/Composing/IComposer.cs) to define Compose with a `IRegister` parameter or a new contract like `IComposition`. At this point it seems to be that trying testing your DI registration is more hassle than it's worth

Answer (score 1):

`Register<TService, TImplementing>` is a static extension method. You cannot mock extension methods, you'll need to look at the source for it & see what method it is calling under the hood.

For example, say I have a `ILogger` which exposes `ILogger.Write(info level, string message)` then I have an extension method:

```
public static void Info(this ILoggerlogger, string message) => logger.Write("Info", message);
```

When `Info` is called on a mocked instance of `ILogger`, the extension method is still called and the mocked `ILogger.Write` is called.

As you can see from [the source code](https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/853087a75044b814df458457dc9a1f778cc89749/src/Umbraco.Core/RegisterExtensions.cs), the generic extension is calling another overload- that's the one you need to setup/verify:

```
composition.Verify(c => c.Register(typeof(IPapermoonContentTypeContainerService), typeof(PapermoonContentTypeContainerService), It.IsAny<Lifetime>()));
```

I'm not familiar with the service composers & suspect it's not possible; but rather than `Compose(Composition composition)`, using `IRegister` (which `Composition` inherits from) would allow you to mock `composition` directly without having to mock it's dependencies...